# DST doesn't work on an Embedded linux distribution (without network connection)

Tags: utc, dst, openembedded, yocto, real-time-clock

I've been trying to set up the DST on an embedded linux, which has intalled a Yocto Project/OpenEmbedded linux distribution.

The first step was to check if the symbolic link from /etc/localtime to /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris was set up.

```
ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Paris /etc/localtime
```

Then the next step seemed to be to knew if the RTC was set up to UTC. Community suggested to check on the file  /etc/sysconfig/clock. Unfortunatley, there isn't such a file on this distribution.

Now, two questions come to my mind: First, exist any other way to check if the RTC is on UTC? Second, Considering a Poky/OpenEmbedded distribution is made by the junction of custom packages, which packages are needed in order to perform a DST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing which packages your image consists of, it's kinda hard to answer.

Though, at least if you're using busybox-hwclock to set the system clock from the RTC, the [hwclock.sh](http://git.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/busybox/files/hwclock.sh) script checks for an UTC variable defined in /etc/default/rcS.

That and the two files /etc/localtime and /etc/timezone ought to be enough. You could also check if TZ is being set (though, /etc/localtime has normally replaced setting TZ).

Comment: Yesterday, the issue was solved. The problem was caused by the files on the /usr/share/zoneinfo/. After checking they were wrong with zdump on a Virtual machine i updated them on the Embedded PC and the DST started to work. Thanks for the information about the check of the TZ